# IoU for semantic segmentation implementation in python/caffe per class

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, metrics, image-segmentation

Is there any recommendable per class IoU(intersection over union) per pixel accuracy(different from bounding box) implementation.I am using caffe and managed to get the mean IoU but i am having difficulty in doing IoU for per class accuracy.I would appreciate a lot if someone could point out a good implementation in any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far this the only close semantic segmentation with multiple pixel label i ve seen so far [here](https://github.com/itijyou/ademxapp/blob/f23da76976ebf12b00df00d351ca95b7c0e6a1e9/issegm/voc.py)