# Sagemaker Semantic Segmentation: iou and pixel accuracy per class

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, semantic-segmentation

I am doing some semantic segemnetation work on AWS sagemaker. My output is the mean iou and pixel accuracy of all my classes but i need more granularity so require the iou and pixel accuracy for each class. This is to see what classes need to be improved.

I imagine its possible but how?

I have had a look at these similar questions but no solution as yet.

[Tensorflow : IOU per class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837529/tensorflow-iou-per-class)

[IoU for semantic segmentation implementation in python/caffe per class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041096/iou-for-semantic-segmentation-implementation-in-python-caffe-per-class)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to compute per class IoU in SageMaker. The only way I can think of is to use the predicted segmentation mask and compute per class IoU yourself. It can be done using GluonCV functions given in https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/_modules/gluoncv/utils/metrics/segmentation.html, particularly code line: mIoU = IoU.mean() can be backtracked to get the functions required to compute IoU.